# Preloading WPF listview with many items

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism, mef

I am using Prism and MEF to create a WPF GUI. I am curious to know if there is a way to pre-populate WPF controls before a user views it.

Specifically, I have a UserControl that uses a ListView to present a list of about 8000 items retrieved via network call over WCF.

I have determined that it is not the network call that is the bottleneck, but rather the creation of the ListView itself. The WPF ShellViewModel currently does a network prefetch so that all required data is present on the client side, but since I am using dependency injection with Prism/MEF, the view does not get created until the user clicks on the Tab containing this ListView and subsequently "freezes" while the ListView is created (populated with the 8K items). I suspect that LazyLoading of view dependencies has a part in this as well.

Is there a way to move this ListView creation to the bootstrapping phase of the application? I would like the have this view loaded/populated before the user clicks on it so that there is no "lag".

Reducing the number of items to be viewed is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your xaml for the listview, datatemplate and so on and your item class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx), sounds like this is exactly what you need.

Comment: listbox is virtualized by default, unless ItemsPanel is specifying a non-virtualized panel.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. I had not heard of such a feature offered by WPF. Looks like that will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Your8kCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        ...
 </ListView>
```